# Time based Delegations possible?

Tags: baking, smart-contracts, delegating

Would it be possible, to make a "time-based-delegation"?

I.E.; I want to delegate for 5 Cycles to Bakery A and after that for 10 Cycles to Bakery B and so on.

Could something like this be realized through a Smart-Contract? How would such a smart-contract look like?

This would open Baking/Delegating for some nice time based campaigns/promotions/charity.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by time-based? Are you asking for a smart-contract to change delegations after time, or a way to detect how long someone has been delegating for?

Comment: The first one. I will change the description.

Answer (score 2):

The SET_DELEGATE instruction can be used to change the contract's delegate.

Contracts cannot currently observe the passage of time in blocks or cycles -- there is no BLOCK_LEVEL instruction. If you are willing to use human time, you can use the NOW instruction to measure time.